# Edit the archive-{custom_page}.php via WP editor

Tags: editor

Is there any way to edit the archive-{custom_posts}.php page via the WP page editor? I wan't to add some custom text and links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you go to `appearance -> editor` in the dashboard your page can show there. Or you can install [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can recommend WP Editor - it is a plugin for WordPress that replaces the default plugin and theme editors as well as the page/post editor.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpide/

[image]